# Formatting DataGridView Column using CultureInfo?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, cultureinfo

I'm using vb.net 2015 (framework 4.5.2).

I want to format a column as currency using CultureInfo since the currency is not static and couold be different from all other places in the program that I use currency. So the default will not work. I tried

```
DGVSelectedBooks.Columns("Price").DefaultCellStyle.Format = String.Format("c2", Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"))
```

but with no success. It does not give error, just does nothing.

Comment: Why don't format it directly?

Comment: How would I format it directly?